# Creating text label of different scales using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, editing, scale

I would like to create a different type of map in ArcMap.I would like to present the frequency of some words. So the dimension of the word (maybe even the color) would symbolize its frequency.

I started by created a polygon for each word and in attribute table I created two columns "word" and "frequency".

How can I use the words from the column "word" to create labels and give them size according to the column "frequency"?

The result I want to obtain is something like this:
http://rising.globalvoicesonline.org/chennai/files/2011/06/figure-1-wordle.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the layer properties>labels tab you can setup multiple labeling classes (under the Method drop down) for your labeling scales.  Labels can be rendered by query using the SQL Query button for each class.  You can also use the Scale Range button to show or not show a certain class within certain scale ranges.